# Missing events on the first day of the month when the first day is a Sunday

Tags: fullcalendar

I've encountered a weird bug when using fullcalendar. Events on the first of the month don't show up on the month view when the first day is on a Sunday.

I tried running my JSON data through fullcalendar's JSBin testing system and couldn't replicate the bug. So I assumed is was something in the include files, but even removing every JS and CSS include and stripping the calendar down to the barest elements hasn't fixed anything.

Here are the includes:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src='calendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='calendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='calendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

The CSS Links:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar/fullcalendar.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" />
```

Here is the calendar activation:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next'
            },
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                url: 'calendar/get-events.php',
                error: function() {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

And a sample from the JSON feed:

```
{"id":"266",
"title":"Sample Event",
"start":"2015-03-01 09:00:00",
"end":"2015-03-01 17:00:00",
"url":"http:\/\/www.websiteaddress.ca\/event-details.php",
"color":"#bfe3ff"}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. after a bit of testing I found a solution. By generating the JSON feed as a Javascript file instead of a JSON file and bypassing get-events.php, the bug went away.

Basically I took this:

```
events: {
                url: 'calendar/demos/php/get-events.php',
                error: function() {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }
```

And changed it to this:

```
            events: {
                url: 'calendar/events.js',
                error: function() {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }
```

So there seems to be something up with the JSON parsing in get-events.php.